# How to serialize the form fields and send it to server, jquery?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have a form in `HTML` which contains multiple same name fields. For example:

```
  <form action="" method="post" id="form">
    <div class="itemsection" id="item1">
      <input type="text" name="Price" />
      <input type="text" name="Name" />
      <input type="text" name="Catagory" />
    </div>
    <div class="itemsection" id="item2">
      <input type="text" name="Price" />
      <input type="text" name="Product" />
      <input type="text" name="Catagory" />
    </div>
    <div class="itemsection" id="item3">
      <input type="text" name="Price" />
      <input type="text" name="Product" />
      <input type="text" name="Catagory" />
    </div>
  </form>
```

Now on the server side (C#), I have an action method and a model class `Product`:

```
    //Action method accepts the form on server //It require the Product array 
    public ActionResult SaveItem(Product[] products)
    {
         .....
         ...
    }

    //Model class product
    public Class Product
    {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public double Price { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string Catagory { get; set; }
    }
```

**Now my question is:** I am submitting the form using `jquery $.ajax method`. On the server side the action method accepts a `Product` class array. Now how can I convert the form fields into a `Json` array (similar to product array). I tried:

```
   $("#form").serialize();  
           &
   $("#form").serializeArray();
```

The first generates the name-value pair of all the form fields and the second generates the name-value array of all the form fields. And my requirement is:

```
  //currently my form contains 3 item section so :
   [
    { "Price" : "value", "Name" : "value", "Catagory" : "value" }, 
    { "Price" : "value", "Name" : "value", "Catagory" : "value" }
    { "Price" : "value", "Name" : "value", "Catagory" : "value" }
   ]
```

Can anyone tell me how can I can achieve this through `JavaScript` or `JQuery`?

Comment: uhm ... [serialize()?](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: Select the divs then use .map() to return the object you expect using the values of the inputs from within the divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `map` method.

```
var data = $('.itemsection').map(function(){
     return {
        Price: $('input[name="Price"]', this).val(),        
        Product: $('input[name="Product"]', this).val(),
        Category: $('input[name="Category"]', this).val()   
     }
}).get();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KRJJ7/

Answer (score 0):

If that's the case you can use `.map()`

```
var arr = $('form :input').map(function() {
              return { 'Price' : $(this).attr('Price') , 
                        'Name' : $(this).attr('Name') ,
                        'Category' : $(this).attr('Category') ,
                      }
          }).get();   // get() will convert them into an array
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jQuery++'s formParams http://jquerypp.com/#formparams